# Parsing time with Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

The code snipped below is trying to extract the hour, minutes and seconds of a string. 
Ex:
"PT5M30S"
"PT1H13M59S"

I am getting a NullPointerException in this line (group=null): int number = new Integer(group.substring(0, group.length()-1));

```
    // Create a Pattern object
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("PT(\\d+H)?(\\d+M)?(\\d+S)?");
    // Now create matcher object.
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(duracaoStr);

    int hour = 0;
    int minute = 0;
    int second = 0;
    if(matcher.matches()){
        for(int i = 1; i<=matcher.groupCount();i++){
            String group = matcher.group(i);
            int number = new Integer(group.substring(0, group.length()-1));
            if(matcher.group(i).endsWith("H")){
                hour = number;
            } else if(matcher.group(i).endsWith("M")){
                minute = number;
            } else if(matcher.group(i).endsWith("S")){
                second = number;
            } 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to compile this code for both the `String`'s individually, one by one.

You'll then notice that this program compiles successfully for the second String i.e., `PT1H13M59S` whereas it gives `NullPointerException` for the first String, i.e., `PT5M30S`

You get this `NullPointerException` from your first String `PT5M30S` because this String doesn't contains `group 1`. Notice that there's no `Hour` value for your first String `PT5M30S`

---

See this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cB2bC1/1):

**RegEx**

```
PT(\d+H)?(\d+M)?(\d+S)?
```

**Input**

```
PT5M30S
PT1H13M59S
```

**Match Information**

```
MATCH 1
2.  [2-4]   `5M`
3.  [4-7]   `30S`
MATCH 2
1.  [10-12] `1H`
2.  [12-15] `13M`
3.  [15-18] `59S`
```

*Notice that in for the first String in Match 1, there's no output for Group 1.*

---

So what you should do is you should perform appropriate validations. Just enclose your code where you're getting `NullPointerException` in `try` `catch` block and if `NullPointerException` occurs, then give default values to all the variables.

For example:,

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("PT(\\d+H)?(\\d+M)?(\\d+S)?");
        // Now create matcher object.
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("PT5M30S");

        int hour = 0;
        int minute = 0;
        int second = 0;

        if (matcher.matches()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                try {
                    String group = matcher.group(i);
                    int number = new Integer(group.substring(0, group.length() - 1));
                    if (matcher.group(i).endsWith("H")) {
                        hour = number;
                    } else if (matcher.group(i).endsWith("M")) {
                        minute = number;
                    } else if (matcher.group(i).endsWith("S")) {
                        second = number;
                    }
                } catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
                    if (i == 1) {
                        hour = 0;
                    } else if (i == 2) {
                        minute = 0;
                    } else if (i == 3) {
                        second = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@rD's solution above is sufficient and well answered ( please choose his ). Just as an alternative I was working on a solution here as well before I realized it was answered properly:
https://github.com/davethomas11/stackoverflow_Q_39443620

```
    // Create a Pattern object
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("PT(\\d+H)?(\\d+M)?(\\d+S)?");
    // Now create matcher object.
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(duracaoStr);

    int hour = 0;
    int minute = 0;
    int second = 0;
    if(matcher.matches()){
        for(int i = 1; i<=matcher.groupCount();i++){
            String group = matcher.group(i);

            //Group will be null if not in pattern
            if (group != null) {
                int number = new Integer(group.substring(0, group.length()-1));
                if(matcher.group(i).endsWith("H")){
                    hour = number;
                } else if(matcher.group(i).endsWith("M")){
                    minute = number;
                } else if(matcher.group(i).endsWith("S")){
                    second = number;
                } 
            }
        }
     }
```

Same thing I've added checking for null.